# http://10.0.2.15 showing up instead of localhost while running hortonworks on VirtualBox on Mac os 10.9

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I needed to try out hadoop so I got to "hortonworks Sandbox". I downloaded the "*.ova", imported it on my VB and started the machine. It gave the message "please open a browser and go to this address" -> `http://10.0.2.15` but nothing happens, no hortonworks GUI shows up. Is there some internet settings I need to configure.

Currently I am running Wi-Fi on proxy setting.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Manual at the web. You have to edit the virtual machine settings. I don't know if you already followed these instructions or which manual you used to set up your hadoop, so let me please know if this helped.

http://de.hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/InstallingHortonworksSandboxonWindowsUsingVMwarePlayerv2.pdf

Comment: Actually hortonworks requires > 4gb ram. My system came to a standstill minutes after running it. Yeah the guide explained well!!

Comment: Today i tried to setup a system with 1,5 gb. Hadoop and the HDFS worked very well but the Ambari-service was down. If you don't need this service you can run your VM with less than 4gb.

Comment: Yeah i guess Ambari and HBase were the ram-suckers there.